# how to reduce dataFrame wisely

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to  transform the following dataFrmae structure where we have details regarding each id and kpi couple of records one with the value_left and the 2nd for the value_right I want to group the 2 records into a single record (as you see in the expected results)

i want to reduce the fillowing dataFrame

```
+---+---+----------+-----------+
| id|kpi|value_left|value_right|
+---+---+----------+-----------+
|  1|sum|        10|       null|
|  1|sum|      null|         20|
|  2|avg|        15|       null|
|  2|avg|      null|         15|
+---+---+----------+-----------+
```

Expected output dataFrame

```
+---+---+----------+-----------+
| id|kpi|value_left|value_right|
+---+---+----------+-----------+
|  1|sum|        10|         20|
|  2|avg|        15|         15|
+---+---+----------+-----------+
```

[expected dataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lJTh.png)

Comment: we can do that by using the filna and groupby but i don't thank that this is the most eligant way to handle this task

Comment: is there any reason why you don't want to `groupby`? I think `groupby` then aggregate using [`first`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) is probably the best approach